# Power BI Store product of previous row subtracting from another column into the next row

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

[Current Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZyep.png)

CntrlRunTot is a hardcoded column of values. I'm trying to make a calculated column that subtracts its previous row from the demand qty that corresponds to its row and have that product stored in the row below. Ex. 188535 - 2976 = 185559 which is then stored a row beneath the 188535 row. Right now my Running Total calculated column depends on every value of CntrlRunTot but I need it to just depend on that first number 188535 and then be able to subtract Demand Qty and store the following values within its consecutive rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by editing the Query (Home=>Transform to get to the query editor from Power BI).

I use the `List.Generate` function to generate a list of the Running Totals; then combine that column with the rest of the table

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next two lines to whatever your data source really is
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Demand Qty", Int64.Type}, {"ContrlRunTot", Int64.Type}, {"Index", Int64.Type}}),

//Add running total column
// Change Table.ToColumns argument to the correct reference
    #"Add Running Total" = Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & 
                {List.Generate(
                    ()=>[rt=#"Changed Type"[ContrlRunTot]{0}, idx=0],
                    each [idx] < Table.RowCount(#"Changed Type"),
                    each [rt = [rt] - #"Changed Type"[Demand Qty]{[idx]+1}, idx=[idx]+1],
                    each [rt])},
                type table[Demand Qty=Int64.Type, ContrlRunTot=Int64.Type, Index=Int64.Type, Running Total=Int64.Type])
in
    #"Add Running Total"
```

[image]

Comment: After going to the Transform tab, where should I go from there? Or am I adding a custom column and then adding that custom column to the table?

Comment: @claired1071 `Home=>Advanced Editor`.  Then you'll have to figure out how to integrate the code I show with what you have.